# Does every Jacobian over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ have everywhere good reduction?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $J$ be the Jacobian of a smooth projective connected curve of genus $g>1$ over the field $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ of algebraic numbers.

Does $J$ have everywhere good reduction?

I know that there are abelian varieties of any dimension which do not have good reduction everywhere. Just take a suitable elliptic curve $E$ and consider the product $E^g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needn't have everywhere good reduction, no.  For instance if $C_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ is a curve which has **semistable bad reduction** at a prime $p$, then this reduction stays semistable bad over any algebraic extension.

For easy examples, take any modular curve $X_0(p)$ for any prime number $p \geq 23$.  Such curves have genus at least $2$ and semistable bad reduction at $p$.

More generally, it is easy to construct for each $g \geq 2$ and prime number $p$ a curve $C_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ of genus $g$ with semistable bad reduction at $p$.  Examples of curves over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (and also defined over *some* number field $K$ and thus also over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$) with these properties (and others...) are constructed in [this paper](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/fixedexistencetheorem2011.pdf) of mine.